# Conditional statements without duplicating code needlessly

Tags: python-3.x

I have two large sections of code which should execute, but only in certain circumstances.

In one circumstances. For example:

1. if 'a' and 'b' and 'c' and 'd' and 'f'
2. then execute all this code below

However, there are two situations when the "code below" should execute, but these situations are mutually exclusive. For example:

1. if SWITCH = True and 'd' and 'f' then skip the condition below and execute all the code in line 3
2. if SWITCH = False and 'a' and 'b' and 'c' and 'd' and 'f'
3. then execute the code below

I have tried using elif, but it doesn't seem practical from the standpoint of duplicaitng code needlessly:

yes, my main goal is to eliminate duplicating the large block of code below the statements. i.e:

if "this"
HUGE block of code
elif "this other thing"
identical HUGE block of code

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `if` and `elif`?

Comment: yes, I updated my original question

Comment: Regardless of the language, whenever you have a huge block of code repeated in multiple places, it can be worth considering if that could be moved to its own function/method

Comment: Also, it sounds like you want a simple Boolean OR operation. I.e. `if (SWITCH = True and 'd' and 'f') or (SWITCH = False and 'a' and 'b' and 'c' and 'd' and 'f')`. This will not perform the second check if the first is true, due to short circuit evaluation

Comment: If I've understood correctly (that the 'code below' is the lower list), since `d AND f` is a subset of `a AND b AND c AND d AND f` , the logic reduces to: 1) if (a AND b AND c AND d AND f ) { if (not SWITCH) {do 2}} {do 3}

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward implementation of your logic is probably (as suggested by Zoey Hewll), to move the "huge block of code" into a separate function or method.

So, this seems to be your requirement in a nutshell:

```
def do_stuff():
    # Lots of code here...
    pass

SWITCH = True
a = True
b = True
c = True
d = True
e = True
f = True

if SWITCH:
    if d and f:
        do_stuff()
else:
    if a and b and c and d and f:
        do_stuff()
```

Comment: There is an added benefit of making the decisions outside the `do_stuff` function in that the context is separate. Should you move the decision inside the function, suddenly the function mixes a lot of different contexts together, making it difficult to reason what is the relationship between the arguments and what are all the separate usecases. Moreover, refactoring affects all the codepaths, instead of isolated parts of the system.